# Creating Function to Parse JSON Data using substring

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, actionscript, substring

i'm working in AS2 & it's looks like javascript alot

**JSON**

```
{
   "name": "Tom",
   "age": 20,
   "state": "usa"
}
```

now i cant parse JSON data in AS2 & need workaround function using substring 
something like that below and i load json file using loadVars()

```
var _lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars()
_lv.onData = function(data)
{
    var ex:Object = eval("data");
 var JSONTOArray:Object = ex.toString().split(',');
 var getname=JSONtoArray[0].substring(JSONtoArray[0].lastIndexOf('"name": "')+9,JSONtoArray[0].lastIndexOf('"')); 
}
_lv.load("MyJSON_URL");
```

now need to build function like

```
getThis('name'); // return Tom
getThis('age'); // return 20
getThis('state'); // return usa
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [existing parser](http://bit.ly/1BIYTVR), because

1. you will not have to write your own code
2. it probably has common syntax like JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc={
   "name": "Tom",
   "age": 20,
   "state": "usa"
};
console.log(abc['name']);     //Tom
console.log(abc['age']);      //20
console.log(abc['state']);    //usa
```

Comment: thanx ozil :) , its helpful .. but it's not working in as2 is there afunction using substring to work in as2 .. thanx again

Comment: @IFollowMohamed what is as2?

Comment: Actionscript 2 [flash coding]

Comment: @IFollowMohamed no idea :)

Comment: i refer to use substring() because its supported in actionscript like the same in javascript

Answer (score 0):

To parse a json data using ActionScript 2, you can use the [JSON.as](http://www.mediafire.com/view/xey8qhibs85bi9j/JSON.as) class ( from [JSON.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20110203044112/http://www.json.org/json.as) ), after putting it in the same directory as your .fla, you can use it like this :

```
import JSON;

var json = new JSON();

var loader:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    loader.onData = function(data)
    {   
        trace(json.parse(data).name);   // gives : Tom
    }
    loader.load('file.json');
```

Hope that can help.